# Write a SOAP request in PHP for a custom XML

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have got a XML format. I need to send SOAP request to the server using PHP. I'm trying with the following code but I see error.

Please find the WSDL here

http://pastie.org/9263788

Sample Request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ISessionManager/Logon</Action>
<h:ContractVersion xmlns:h="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">330</h:ContractVersion>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<LogonRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService">
  <logonRequestData xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <d4p1:DomainCode>WWW</d4p1:DomainCode>
    <d4p1:AgentName>API****</d4p1:AgentName>
    <d4p1:Password>********</d4p1:Password>
    <d4p1:LocationCode i:nil="true" />
    <d4p1:RoleCode>APIB</d4p1:RoleCode>
    <d4p1:TerminalInfo i:nil="true" />
  </logonRequestData>
</LogonRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The Code

```
<?php
$test->DomainCode = 'CODE';
$test->AgentName = 'AgentName';
$test->Password = 'Password';
$test->RoleCode = 'Role'; 

$wsdl = "https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/sessionmanager.svc?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

try {    
$logon_request = $client->Logon($test);
print_r($logon_request);
echo "success!";
} 
catch (SoapFault $soap_error) {
echo $soap_error;
echo "error!";
}
?>
```

Method name is Logon. I have also been given another link to use but how do I use this?

```
https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com (The urls can't be view from all IPs)
```

Am I sending correct request??

Error

```
SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php(13): SoapClient->__call('Logon', Array) #1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php(13): SoapClient->Logon(Array) #2 {main}error!
```

Following is the response I should be getting.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header />
<s:Body>
<LogonResponse xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">
<Signature>signature data</Signature>
</LogonResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: You don't send a raw XML soap request with SoapClient. It converts the local object to XML for you

Comment: OK. please have a look at the WSDL provided with pastie link. Also can you help me set the soap request with appropriate PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

You use local php data types (like arrays and objects) and pass those to the SoapClient. For your example, it would be something like:

```
$test->DomainCode = 'CODE',
$test->AgentName = 'AgentName',
$test->Password = 'Password',
$test->RoleCode = 'Role';

$wsdl = "https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/sessionmanager.svc?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

try {    
    $logon_request = $client->Logon($test);
    print_r($logon_request);
    echo "success!";
} catch (SoapFault $soap_error) {
    echo $soap_error;
    echo "error!";
}
```

Comment: I get the same error. Have you seen my edited question? I have been given another link to be added.

Comment: You are probably getting same error but for a different reason. The error indicates that a non-object was used, so probably SoapClient or remote soap server can't swap between array and object as most can, so pass in an object with values. updated answer.

Comment: Also, your update shows that you are passing in an array but also shows you are still passing in raw XML. Is that the case?

Comment: I used the same code you wrote. I am supposed to use this url too https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com But I'm not using it in the code.

Comment: Update question with code used and newest version of error.

Comment: I've added 'I get an empty result'. No errors. i tried __getLastRequest() which also returns nothing.

Comment: Try `echo $soap_error;` as it has a built in `__toString()` method anyway. also notice i've added some non-soap output to determine where it is failing.

Comment: Try without the soap header. Updated answer

Comment: Set `$test` to object like in answer

Comment: I've used semicolon at the end of each line as Dreamweaver threw syntax error. I still get the same error.

Comment: I've got a working API in PHP which also sends header. Can you use the url to solve this issue? http://pastie.org/9264123

Comment: That looks like a totally different approach, as it's passing in login info in the soap header itself, not using Logon method. Is there a public URL for the api that works?

Comment: No public. it can only be access from a specific IP. I can get you the function and types along with WSDL if you want.